# Execute command from DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I have the following code:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">                      
                        <GridView                    
                    Background="Azure"
                    x:Name="ContactList"                  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">

                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                                    Command="{Binding MyCommandOnTheViewModel, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>                              
                                <Border Width="300" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1">                                   
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />                            
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Age}" />                                      
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Button>
                                                <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>                                 
                                </Border>                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>                       
                    </GridView>
                    </StackPanel>
```

At this point, the Command: `MyCommandOnTheViewModel` gets executed when I click on an item in the list. As you can see I also have a `StackPanel` containing two buttons. How Can I Bind two separate Commands to each button?

I´ve been trying to give my buttons names thinking that I could somehow do something like:

```
 <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged" ELEMENTNAME="MyButtonsName">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                                    Command="{Binding MyCommandOnTheViewModel, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

But there does not seem to work like that.
Any tips appreciated!

This is what worked for me:

```
<Button Content="MyButton"                                                  
Command ="{Binding ElementName=ContactList,Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"></Button>
```

Thanks you for all help @Utsav

Answer (score 0):

You can give `Command` property to each button. In that way you can easily bind two seperate commands in viewmodel with the two buttons, on click event.

See the code below.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">                      
                <GridView                    
                Background="Azure"
                x:Name="ContactList"                  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">

                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                                Command="{Binding MyCommandOnTheViewModel, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                              
                            <Border Width="300" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1">                                   
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />                            
                                <Run Text="{Binding Age}" />                                      
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding CommandLeftBtn}"></Button>
                                            <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding CommandRightBtn}"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>                                 
                            </Border>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>                       
                </GridView>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I cant add the command on the button this way because im inside of the GridView.  I do not have direct acess to the vm.

Comment: Give the name of your page as Page. And then try this: <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandLeftBtn, ElementName=Page}">

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatley all I can bind to from within the GridView is the Gridviews ItemSource.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in the above comment? That should work, it has worked in my case.

Comment: Yes I have. Maybe it does not work for me beacuse i usee MVVM-lights viewModelLocator. My DataContext looks like this:
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=UserViewModel}"

Comment: You can try one more thing. Give the outer most grid a name "LayoutRoot" and try the above by giving this name as ElementName. <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandLeftBtn, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">

Comment: Thank you very much for trying. Unfortunatley it did not work. I think I need to use some kind of interactiontrigger.

Comment: Yes in that case you can use trigger within each button to bind to a command. <Button ....><Interactivity:....></Button>

Comment: Yes but my buttons are inside the Gridview so I get the same problem there =)